# What are some software options for compressing images other than photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am wondering if there are better options out there for compressing images other than Photoshop.

Does Adobe offer a product that specializes in compressing images or does a better job than Photoshop?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Which format are the images are you trying to compress? And what kind of image is it?  i.e. a photographic image, or graphics of some kind?

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi Billy, the images are JPGs. And they are examples of my work. So some photos but mostly vector stuff exported to JPG.

I ended up using a site called Shortpixel. I am not sure it gave me better results than what I could have gotten out of Photoshop.

Comment: Definitely [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac) if you have a Mac. They also list some [alternatives for other platforms](https://imageoptim.com/versions) in the website. It's not the only image compressing tool out there and it's not the only one that I use, but it's the one I always end up promoting because it's free and really good at what it does. It supports jpg, png, gif and svg.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the amount of JPEG compression when saving in virtually all decent raster image editors, such as Photoshop, GIMP (which is free), Krita (also free), CorelPaint, Affinity Photo etc.

In terms of being "better", I can't answer that. Better is a highly subjective term.

Note also that it is not a good idea to add more compression to an existing JPEG, since recompressing always degrades image quality.  You should really begin with an original image in a lossless format to get the best quality in a JPEG.

By the way, compressed jpegs are really more suited to photographic images. For other kinds of images such as graphics with solid areas of colour, adding more compression will cause unpleasant artefacts no matter what software you use.  You would be better to use a lossless format such as PNG for those kind of graphics.

Answer (score 1):

"Better job" is a relative term.

There are some aspects I can consider on your premises.

### Better quality

This applies only to lossy compression, more specifically to JPG files.

Photoshop, PhotoPaint, and some other programs can use a type of JPG compression called 4:4:4 which has the best quality, (less data loss) and have a good ratio of compression.

At some point, this advantage fades away when using more aggressive compression ratios vs 4:2:2 format.

This can sound alien to you. Please use google translate o this really old paper I made years ago, but you can have an idea of what do I mean: https://otake.com.mx/Apuntes/Imagen/PruebasDeCompresion/

<sub>Yes. I will update that, sometime in the future...</sub>

Some other file formats have different compression algorithms, but the difference between them and the settings are negligible so you never see a configuration for them, like in the case of PNG.

---

### Other parameters

But you can also mean ease of use, batch compression, batch resampling, and converting...

In those cases, you can check ImageMagick as @Lucian recommended. But I personally use IrfanView irfanview.com on Windows, which has a clean interface and does a pretty good job for batch process. It can also use a 4:4:4 quantization, in this case, it has a text that says "Use 1x1 blocks".

---

### And you are not referring to

**Resampling**

If your premise is only having the same size image using less bandwidth, compression is your goal. But a lot of times what people need is resampling it, so the image is smaller in size, and then using compression.

**Using another format**

There are also some other image formats like WebP or AVIF, that could have better compression ratios than Jpg, depending on what you need the image for.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) is a free tool for basic image manipulation, this includes resaving with compression.

Answer (score -1):

Just use Paint. Any image editor can do this; try IrfanView, it's a free software to view and edit RAW photos.